# how can three cells work in parallel the incoming workpiece carriers in Analogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to create a conveyor line where three cells do the same work in parallel to reduce the cycle time.
Workflow:
Workpiece carrier = WT: 12 pieces
3x cells
The WT should always be directed to the cell that is free or the work process is most likely to finish.

Since I have just started to get to learn about Anylogic, I am having a hard time setting the correct commands.
If someone has an idea of how to reach my goal I would be very grateful!

[image]

Comment: Hi, this place works best for you if you ask very *specific* questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question if far too broad ("setting the correct commands"??). I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focussed on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Review the implementation in the Solar Panel Production Line Example model inside the AnyLogic help, or download the source form the AnyLogic Cloud
https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/29d54a61-aaac-4c47-8e50-941c0f5bb36e?mode=SETTINGS

Easiest would be to use a select output and base the selection of the exit from the select output on the condition of whether one of the cells are busy or not

[image]

[image]

In your example, you need to replace the code of `randomFrom(collection)` with a function to check if a cell is busy or not. Since you don't have the cells in your example I cant give you the code. But try it yourself and if you cant manage after reviewing the example model then post a new question